# Lost calendar icon on 4S iPhone

Tags: ios, calendar, recovery

My calendar icon accidentally got deleted. How do I recover & restore that icon to my screen.

Answer (score 2):

At least on un-jailbroken phones it is not possible to delete the standard applications, so the icon (and the app) are still on your phone. Try to

- Use Spotlight search to search for "Calendar"
- Go to Settings -> General -> "Reset" (last option) -> Home Screen to reset the home screen to its factory state

Answer (score 2):

Calendar is a "system app", and because of this, the app can't be fully deleted.

This means that it's probably just been moved to one of your other screens.

Try doing a spotlight search for the application, by either going to the left-most page in iOS6, or by swiping down in iOS 7.

This *should* indicate the name of the folder it's hiding in.